# Batch - Removing elements from an Array

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I believe that the answer to this should be pretty simple.  I grab a list of dirs from a place and store them into a text document.  I then read the text document names and store them into an array.  At the end of this process I would like to have all the entries from the array wiped.

The reason I would like to do this, is because I am going to go though several folder locations and storing them into the same array.  However when I don't clear the array each time it seems to give me all kinds of heck when I try to print it out later on down the line.

I need a fresh array each time I go to fill in the next folder.

```
REM **************************************************************************
                REM this part needs to delete the value but doesnt
                set !array[%arraywiper%]!=0

REM **************************************************************************
```

This is an example of the problem I am having. the code below can be ran to see what I am talking about.

```
ECHO OFF & setLocal EnableDELAYedExpansion
cls

REM creates folder for text doc
IF EXIST "c:\TEMP" (echo.) else (md c:\TEMP\)

REM Scans C:\Program Files (x86) and stores into a text doc
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:D-H-S /on /b "C:\Program Files (x86)"') do echo %%a)> c:\TEMP\dork_array_wipe.txt

REM Counts the folders in the text doc
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\"*) do ( 
set /a locationcount+=1 
)

REM Stores the values from the doc into an array
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\TEMP\dork_array_wipe.txt") do (
set /A i+=1
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
)

set arraywiper=1

:Arraywipeloop19

IF %arraywiper%==%locationcount% GOTO Arraywipecomplete19 else (

                    REM Prints array to show value entered array
                    echo array (%arraywiper%): !array[%arraywiper%]!


    REM **************************************************************************
                    REM this part needs to delete the value but doesnt
                    set !array[%arraywiper%]!=0

    REM **************************************************************************              

                    Set /a arraywiper+=1

                    REM Prints out array in question to veryify change took place
                    echo array (%arraywiper%): !array[%arraywiper%]!
                    GOTO Arraywipeloop19
                    )

:Arraywipecomplete19


pause
```

Mr. Rojo has given me an excellent solution to this issue.  This is an example of how it works.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "array[0]=foo"
set "array[1]=bar"
set "array[2]=baz"
set "array[3]=qux"
set "array[4]=quux"
set "array[5]=corge"

echo.
echo first printout

echo %array[0]%, %array[1]%, %array[2]%, %array[3]%, %array[4]%, %array[5]%
pause


rem // starting with element 3, delete 2 elements and insert 3 new
call :splice array 3 2 grault garply waldo

echo.
echo second printout

echo %array[0]%, %array[1]%, %array[2]%, %array[3]%, %array[4]%, %array[5]%, %array[6]%, %array[7]%
pause
call :splice array 0 

REM set array[

REM goto :EOF

echo.
echo third printout

echo %array[0]%, %array[1]%, %array[2]%, %array[3]%, %array[4]%, %array[5]%, %array[6]% 

pause

set "array[0]=foo"
set "array[1]=bar"
set "array[2]=baz"
set "array[3]=qux"
set "array[4]=quux"
set "array[5]=corge"

echo.
echo fourth printout

echo %array[0]%, %array[1]%, %array[2]%, %array[3]%, %array[4]%, %array[5]%, %array[6]% 

pause




:splice <array_name> <startIDX> [<deleteCount> [<item1> [<item2> [...]]]]
rem // works like JavaScript Array.prototype.splice()
rem // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=Array.prototype.splice()
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a idx = 0, argskip = 0, inserted = 0, orig_ubound = -1
if "%~3"=="" (set /a "resume = 1 << 30") else set /a resume = %~2 + %~3
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set %~1[') do (
    set /a orig_ubound += 1
    if !idx! lss %~2 (
        set "tmp[!idx!]=%%J"
        set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
    ) else (
        if !inserted! equ 0 (
            for %%# in (%*) do (
                set /a argskip += 1, inserted = 1
                if !argskip! gtr 3 (
                    set "tmp[!idx!]=%%~#"
                    set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1, resume += 1
                )
            )
        )
        if !idx! geq !resume! (
            set "tmp[!idx!]=%%J"
            set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
        ) else set /a resume -= 1
    )
)
set "r=endlocal"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[" %%I in ('2^>NUL set tmp[') do (
    set "r=!r!&set "%~1[%%J""
)
for /L %%I in (%idx%,1,%orig_ubound%) do set "r=!r!&set "%~1[%%I]=""
%r%&exit/b
```

Comment: Get rid of the `!`s in the `set` statement.

Comment: `setlocal` before building the array.  Output all array values by simply doing `set array`. When you want to destroy the array, `endlocal`.

Comment: @ SomethingDark   Getting rid of the ! 's  did nothing except break the code.  If I remove the !'s the code no longer outputs anything. I tried just removing the !'s in the array purge portion, but it did nothing.

Comment: @rojo   I don't fully understand what you are asking me to do.  An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an illustration of what I commented above, demonstrating the use of `setlocal` and `endlocal` to forget variables.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set idx=0

rem // populate array
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d') do (
    set "array[!idx!]=%%~nxI"
    set /a idx += 1
)

rem // display array
set array[

rem // destroy array
endlocal

rem // result
set array[
```

Or if you prefer to loop through the array elements rather than using `set` to output their values:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set idx=0

rem // populate array
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d') do (
    set "array[!idx!]=%%~nxI"
    set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
)

rem // display array
for /L %%I in (0,1,%ubound%) do echo array[%%I]: !array[%%I]!

rem // destroy array
endlocal

rem // result
echo %array[0]%
```

---

**Edit:** If you must manipulate the collection of variables with indexed array-ish methods, I wrote a `:splice` function that works similarly to JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).  You can use this to remove elements, insert elements, a combination of both, and even to clear the entire array if you wish.  (Just `call :splice arrayname 0` to unset all elements from the array.)

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "array[0]=foo"
set "array[1]=bar"
set "array[2]=baz"
set "array[3]=qux"
set "array[4]=quux"
set "array[5]=corge"

rem // starting with element 3, delete 2 elements and insert 3 new
call :splice array 3 2 grault garply waldo

set array[

goto :EOF

:splice <array_name> <startIDX> [<deleteCount> [<item1> [<item2> [...]]]]
rem // works like JavaScript Array.prototype.splice()
rem // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=Array.prototype.splice()
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a idx = 0, argskip = 0, inserted = 0, orig_ubound = -1
if "%~3"=="" (set /a "resume = 1 << 30") else set /a resume = %~2 + %~3
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set %~1[') do (
    set /a orig_ubound += 1
    if !idx! lss %~2 (
        set "tmp[!idx!]=%%J"
        set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
    ) else (
        if !inserted! equ 0 (
            for %%# in (%*) do (
                set /a argskip += 1, inserted = 1
                if !argskip! gtr 3 (
                    set "tmp[!idx!]=%%~#"
                    set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1, resume += 1
                )
            )
        )
        if !idx! geq !resume! (
            set "tmp[!idx!]=%%J"
            set /a ubound = idx, idx += 1
        ) else set /a resume -= 1
    )
)
set "r=endlocal"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[" %%I in ('2^>NUL set tmp[') do (
    set "r=!r!&set "%~1[%%J""
)
for /L %%I in (%idx%,1,%orig_ubound%) do set "r=!r!&set "%~1[%%I]=""
%r%&exit/b
```

Comment: Do you know of  a way to delete just one element of the array?  I have read that it can be difficult.

Comment: Just `set "array[!idx!]="`. The batch language doesn't really have a proper Array object in the traditional sense. You're actually setting 20 variables with similar names (give or take), rather than populating a single object with multiple values. It's not difficult at all. `set "array[5]="` would set the variable named `%array[5]%` to nothing -- and therefore would undefine it. What might be difficult is if you'd then want to reindex your suspicious-quote "array". That would be a challenge, and (although not impossible) would be something better suited for a different scripting language.

Comment: So upon further testing.  I have decided that the solution given, using set local and end local, is not a true solution.  The reason I do not see this as a solution anymore is because using this method you cannot extract any information from the array.  If you try to store any variables from that array it will all be destroyed when the end local is used.  I could export the info to a text document and then read that info, but this is a work around and not truely what I am looking for.

Comment: @Magnes3d Just for fun I wrote a `:splice` function the other night that might be what you're looking for.  See if you find my edit useful.

Comment: So far I have glazed over it.  I am not sure yet how it works or how to use it.  I put it in a batch to run it to see what it did.  But it just disappears as soon as I click it.  So I assume that this is something I would put in my code and call as I need it.  Hey I am still learning, so I am sorry if I am hard to explain stuff too.  I am learning as I go.

Comment: The link you put in the code is very helpful.  This is a really neat piece of code you have generated.  I am going to keep playing with this.  Again Thank you for your help.  I am learning how to code and you are helping me along.  Thank you.

Comment: @Magnes3d Rather than double-clicking the script to launch it, open a cmd prompt and type the name of the script.  When the script finishes, the console remains open.  Or you could insert a `pause` immediately above `goto :EOF`.  And thank you!  It *is* a neat piece of code, if I do say so myself.  `:)`

Comment: OK WELL! I dont know about all this console stuff.  But I do know this.  That code is perfect.  It is great.  I can put this into all kinds of stuff.  This is a wonderful answer to the problem that is array's in batch.  I was toying around with it and this is what I have done and I think I understand a little better.  I would like to fully understand what you wrote but that is going to take much more time then the little I have right now.

Comment: Nice Bat_Array.prototype.splice() ! +1

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in batch can also be emulated through lists in conjunction with index variables to match elements to an index value

the below uses macro's to demonstrate how to, for a list type Array emulation:

- modify the original list or return the result to a cloned list
- splice new element/s at a supplied index
- Extract specific element/s by index number
- remove element/s from the list.

Each macro accepts Args through a combination of:

- Substring Modification

  - replacing `{e}` with the `array` varname and `array clone / return` varname
  - the splice macro's second Arg is the Index new values are to be inserted at
- For loop If else construct

  - capture the Index number/s to act upon.

The use of macro's and lists as opposed to called functions or assignment of a large number of values to associated variables allows for considerably faster execution.

The Splice macro includes a method of verification

```bat
@Echo off

rem /* Macro Definition - Arg order mandatory in each macro. */
(Set \n=^^^
%= Newline var for macro definitions. Do Not Modify =%
)
::: Reserved Variable names used for Macro's:
::: \n Splice Extract Remove Groupname Insert Prepend Append Rvar RV cArr
::: {i} {i#} Tokens

rem /* Usage: %Splice:{e}={ListVarName}{Insertion Index}{OPTIONAL-NewListVarname}% */
Set Splice=For %%n in (1 2)do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 For /F "Tokens=1,2,3 Delims={}" %%1 in ("{e}") Do (%\n%
  Set "Groupname=%%1"%\n%
  Set "{i#}=%%2"%\n%
  Set "cArr=%%3"%\n%
 )%\n%
 Set "Prepend="%\n%
 Set "Append="%\n%
 Set "{i}=0"%\n%
 For %%G in (!Groupname!)Do For %%E in (!%%G!)Do (%\n%
  If !{i}! LSS !{i#}! (%\n%
   If "!Prepend!" == "" (Set "Prepend=%%E")Else (Set "Prepend=!Prepend! %%E")%\n%
  )%\n%
  If !{i}! GEQ !{i#}! (%\n%
   If "!Append!" == "" (Set "Append=%%E")Else (Set "Append=!Append! %%E")%\n%
  )%\n%
  Set /A "{i}+=1"%\n%
 )%\n%
  If Not "!cArr!" == "" (Set "!cArr!=!Prepend! !Insert! !Append!")Else (Set "!Groupname!=!Prepend! !Insert! !Append!")%\n%
)Else Set Insert=

rem /* Usage: %Remove:{e}={ListVarName}{OPTIONAL-NewListVarname}% Index/es to be removed as Integer list */
Set Remove=For %%n in (1 2)do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%1 in ("{e}") Do (%\n%
  Set "Groupname=%%1"%\n%
  Set "cArr=%%2"%\n%
  Set "Rvar="%\n%
 )%\n%
 Set "Prepend="%\n%
 Set "Append="%\n%
 Set "{i}=0"%\n%
 For %%G in (!Groupname!)Do For %%E in (!%%G!)Do (%\n%
  Set /A "{i}+=1"%\n%
  Set "{i#}=1"%\n%
  For %%t in (!Tokens!)Do If %%t EQU !{i}! Set "{i#}=0"%\n%
  If !{i#}! EQU 1 (%\n%
   If "!Rvar!" == "" (Set "Rvar=%%E")Else (Set "Rvar=!Rvar! %%E")%\n%
  )%\n%
 )%\n%
 If Not "!cArr!" == "" (Set "!cArr!=!Rvar!")Else (Set "!Groupname!=!Rvar!")%\n%
)Else Set Tokens=

rem /* Usage: %Extract:{e}={ListVarName}{OPTIONAL-ReturnVarName[Default - RV ]}%Index/es to be extracted as Integer list */
Set Extract=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%1 in ("{e}") Do (%\n%
  Set "Groupname=%%1"%\n%
  Set "Rvar=%%2"%\n%
  If "!Rvar!" == "" ( Set "Rvar=RV" )%\n%
 )%\n%
 Set "{i}=0"%\n%
  Set "!Rvar!="%\n%
 For %%G in (!Groupname!)Do For %%E in (!%%G!)Do (%\n%
  Set /A "{i}+=1"%\n%
  For %%v in (!{i#}!)Do If !{i}! EQU %%v (%\n%
   For %%r in (!Rvar!)Do If "!%%r!" == "" ( Set "!Rvar!=%%E" )Else ( Set "!Rvar!=!%%r! %%E" )%\n%
  )%\n%
 )%\n%
)Else Set {i#}=

rem /* Delayed Expansion Must be enabled to expand macro's */ ::: EXAMPLE USAGES:
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set List=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Set list
Echo/rem /* insert new elements. Example = insert "9 9" after the 3rd element. */
%Splice:{e}={List}{3}%9 9
Set List
Echo/rem /* extract element/s. example = 1st 4th and 6th elements */
%Extract:{e}={List}{YourReturnVar}%1 4 6
Set YourReturnVar
Echo/rem /* remove elements from list. example=remove the 1st 4th and 6th elements */
%Remove:{e}={List}%1 4 6
Set List
Echo/rem /* Clone existing list; inserting elements . Example = insert previously extracted elements
Echo/rem    at the max index [ from the last {i} index returned ] */
%Splice:{e}={List}{!{i}!}{clone}%!YourReturnVar!
Set Clone
```

Output of Example:

[image: Output of Example]