# How to access the individual items in a variable in Windows Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this list in batch:

```
set list=12,34,56
echo %list%
```

How can I get the list to print only 34?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Im using windows 10 Pro

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64762748/12343998) for a means of access elements of a list by index.

Comment: @aschipfl With all due respect, the question linked as duplicate is like recommending a sledgehammer to kill a fly ;-) [How to loop through comma separated string in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158719/how-to-loop-through-comma-separated-string-in-batch) may be a closer match.

Comment: I see, @dxiv, you're right; once I'm at a computer I'll add the link you're suggested (it can't be done via mobile)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the second number `34`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ("%list%") do @echo %%a
```

To print all 3 numbers `12 34 56`:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("%list%") do @echo %%a %%b %%c
```

The double percents in `%%a` are required in a batch file. At the command prompt, use just `%a`.